# Missing registry key for IUIAutomation

Tags: c++, com, ui-automation

I'm trying to use the UI Automation sample on msdn located here;

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/UI-Automation-Document-24a37c82#content

i keep getting the error message: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered

The Microsoft example uses this line to create an instance of the CUIAutomation8;

CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CUIAutomation8), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&_automation));

which is the part it seems to be failing at, from digging around this seems to be getting the id of the class and then checking the registry key at that location ({E22AD333-B25F-460C-83D0-0581107395C9} in this case) however my machine doesn't have this key already entered which i think is causing the error, i'm not sure if i'm having to install anything extra that i'm currently missing? As of now all i've done is download the sample and tried compiling it

any help would be much appreciated!

note: I'm using windows 7 with SP1 and VS2015

i've also tried changing CUIAutomation8 to IUIAutomation instead but i'm getting the same issue but as a different registry key

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. What Windows version are you using?

Comment: windows 7 with SP 1, also running it on VS2015 (will add this to the original question)

Comment: `CUIAutomation8` is documented to need Windows 8 or higher https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448746(v=vs.85).aspx for Windows 7, try `CUIAutomation` (w/o 8)

Comment: ah perfect, that worked straight away, ofcourse it's just a simple "read the documentation" issue, thanks for your help! you've posted as a comment, is there anyway i can mark your reply as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CUIAutomation8` is documented to need [Windows 8 or higher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448746(v=vs.85).aspx) for Windows 7, you want to use `CUIAutomation`